# Split string into elements of a string array

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I've got a string with the format of:

> blockh->127.0.0.1 testlocal.de->127.0.0.1 testlocal2.com

Now I need to seperate the elements, best way would be a string array I think. I would need to get only these elements seperated:

> 127.0.0.5 somerandompage.de
>
> 127.0.0.1 anotherrandompage.com

How to split and filter the array to get only these elements?

Using the .Filter() Methode doesn't to the job.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question. It is not only about splitting, but also about filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string `Split` method:

```
 var st = "blockh->127.0.0.1 testlocal.de->127.0.0.1 testlocal2.com";
 var result = st.Split(new [] { "->" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can achieve the same with a Regex:

```
var result = Regex.Split(st, "->");
```

As a note from @Chris both of these will split the string into an array with 3 elements:

- blockh
- 127.0.0.1 testlocal.de
- 127.0.0.1 testlocal2.com

In case you want to get rid of blockh, you can do a regex match using an IP address and domain regex:

```
 var ip = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b\s*(([\w][\w\-\.]*)\.)?([\w][\w\-]+)(\.([\w][\w\.]*))");
 var result = ip.Matches(st).Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToArray();
```

This will get only the two elements containing IP addresses.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that you will get "blockh" as the first element which may or may not be desired...

Comment: That's Right. Updating my answer ;)

Comment: Would the example using RegEx give ma an array of 2 fields containing my preferenced elements?

Comment: Updated the regex to match the IP and Domain. Now it gets the two strings you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string `Split()` method to do that.

```
var s = "testlocal->testlocal2";
var splitted = s.Split(new[] {"->"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //result splitted[0]=testlocal, splitted[1]=testlocal2
```

Comment: I edited above, content isn't the same all the time. It's variable.

Comment: @Chris yeah, fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

If the simpler versions for splitting a string don't work for you, you will likely be served best by defining a Regular Expression and extracting matches.

That is described in detail in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx

For more information on how Regular Expressions can look this page is very helpful: http://regexone.com/

Comment: I don't need to get "blockh". RegEx is overloaded I think, any easier way without RegEx?